# How can I use diffrent persistence unit in my DAO classes depending on maven phase (Install or test)?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jpa, persistence

Currently I'm working on a Java webapp and we are using two databases: in-Mem database for unit tests and mysql for production. So we have two persistence units in the persistence.xml and we want to get the EntityManager instance depending on the maven build lifcycle phase (test: hsqldb, install: mysql).
Is there any way to do that for example by injecting something?

Many thanks

Comment: I think you want to use different "profile" values in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do that is to have a test-specific `persistence.xml` file under `src/test/resources/META-INF`. This will appear before the production `persistence.xml` file in the runtime classpath, so it will be the one to get loaded.